# Facebook Login with RNFirebase on android

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, facebook-authentication

When I set up my application using quick start for Android at Meta for developers in section "Tell us about your Android project" after I paste my app details I get the following error:

```
One or more invalid package name(s). Make sure package names are associated with a valid Google Play store URL.
```

Would you please be able to tell me why is it showing and what I need to do to make it work? I took my package name from the build.gradle defaultConfig.applicationId as there was no package attribute on the manifest tag in AndroidManifest.xml (which I added).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error, and after spamming the "Save" button, I succeeded. It's quite tricky, but if you're still stuck, give it a try.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).